# Xpath to exclude nodes after match

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse some data that has every cell of a tabs in a `<text />` node. I need to ignore nodes that start with the star character `*` as well as 4 nodes after it. Can this be done with xpath, or do I need to go about this in a different way?

**EDIT**: My XML looks like the following:

```
<page>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 1</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 2</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 3</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 4</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 5</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">* ROW 2 CELL 1</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 2 CELL 2</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 2 CELL 3</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 2 CELL 4</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 2 CELL 5</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 1</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 2</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 3</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 4</text>
    <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 5</text>
</page>
```

Comment: Better show an example... you're using "node" in a way that's unclear - maybe "element" and "element text"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following expression:

```
 /*/text[not(starts-with(., '*')) and 
         not(preceding::*[position()<5][starts-with(., '*')])]
```

Selects the following against your input:

```
<root>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 1</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 2</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 3</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 4</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 5</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 1</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 2</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 3</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 4</text>
  <text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 5</text>
</root>
```

All of `ROW 2` is skipped.

The following expression is equivalent (by De Morgan's laws):

```
/*/text[not(starts-with(., '*') or 
            preceding::*[position()<5][starts-with(., '*')])]
```

Comment: Nice solution - Thanks for your observations on mine :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
//text[starts-with(.,"*")]/preceding-sibling::text 
| //text[starts-with(.,"*")]/following-sibling::text[position() > 4]
```

For the provided input this returns the desired nodes

```
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 1</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 2</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 3</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 4</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 1 CELL 5</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 1</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 2</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 3</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 4</text>
<text attr="123" attr2="1234">ROW 3 CELL 5</text>
```

However as @lwburk points out in comments it does not work for the general case if you have multiple nodes that begin with *. This is because the `|` operator paired with the two statements ends up selecting everything before and after both matching nodes. His solution correctly handles both situations.

Comment: Couple observations: 1) You have an off-by-one error; 2) this (almost) works on the provided input, but it won't work on larger examples (e.g. try adding a `ROW 4` that begins with a `*`).